# When to use plist?

Tags: ios, plist

I know what plist does but what is the general purpose of plist?

Is it good idea to use it to write/read data with it?

Sorry for broad question.
Thank you

Comment: "I know what plist does" What does it do?

Comment: It stores data in dictionary type root... When I create swift project, it comes along with info.plist, and it just stores version info, base storyboard, etc.

Comment: plists are used a lot for application related things like you've mentioned info.plist which tells the OS important things about your app. It's used elsewhere for preferences bundle settings and I think NSDefaults uses plists. A plist is analogous to the ubiquitous '.ini" file on that _other_ OS. Whether **you** want to use plists for storing your user's data or meta-data depends on how complex that data is. Many apps require more complex data persistence, i.e. NSCoder or Core Data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your app has a big constant that it uses, like the names of all the countries in the world in alphabetical order. That's an array of strings. How will you create that constant?

One way might be to type the whole array in code, a really big array.

It might be easier to configure this as a *.plist* file and read the file into an array as your app launches.

So, that is one use of a *.plist* file: it's a text rendering in a canonical format for data that you will need to use during the app's lifetime.

And of course the same thing works in reverse; you could save an array of strings as a *.plist* file while the app runs, in order to read it again the next time the app runs. (That in fact is how UserDefaults works.)

Comment: Hmm... I see.So then plist is more like static constant holder. Is it not good idea to write(update) dynamically from mobile application?

Comment: In my second example ("in reverse") it might certainly be dynamically updated. It's just a convenient format for serializing to disk.

Comment: If you want it to be dynamically updated, it might not be the best use of a plist. Think of it as UserDefaults. If they are constantly changing, its better to use a Dictionary at first and once you are sure that no more changes would occur, then write to a file. Else you would be introducing the overhead of constantly reading and writing to a file.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help.
#SagarU: that is the case of my use.

Comment: Obviously you would only need this in order to ensure persistence beyond this lifetime of the app. If the app never terminates, data can be held in memory, especially if it is not overly large. But if data is very large or you need it to persist even after termination, writing out to a file is the only way to go. A _.plist_ can be a convenient format, though it is not the only possibility by any means.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a plist as a file-based implementation of a `Dictionary` (or `NSDictionary`). What you have inside are key-value pairs which you can parse and use as part of your logic.
If you might have observed, there would be a [`Info.plist`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html) file in every project. It stores values for different configurations you might want to add. An example would be `NSAppTransportSecurity`

Once you have the values in the file, you can use it as:

```
    var configDict: NSDictionary?
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist") {
    configDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}
if let dict = myDict {
    // Use configDict here
}
```

Keep in mind that you are not limited just to the default Info.plist that comes bundled with the project.  You can create one of your own too. Consider the scenario where your are fetching a number of configurations at launch. You can save it as a plist and reference later.

Answering the second part of your question, reading and writing to a file, if performed at very short intervals, seems like a unnecessary overhead. Its better to use local Dictionary variables and then write at longer time intervals or when you are sure that changes are done. Plist is more of a kind of persistent storage. So you can opt to write to the file when the app enters background or user kills the app.

**Note: Keep in mind that plist is essentially a plain file in your file system. There is nothing to prevent someone from reading it (and I know about sandboxing). That is why its wise to never store any passwords etc in a plist (nor in UserDefaults).**

Comment: Yes, but is it appropriate to use plist as my mobile application's database? I tried both NSObject and Realm, but did not work out well. Plist does work for mobile application...

Comment: the question has previously been tagged with Swift. Meanwhile, the tags were edited and i removed the comment right away!

Comment: My bad. I changed the code to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Plists are convenient for when you need to store small amounts of persistent data. The API is simple. Large plist files are not recommended. [Apple suggests less than a few hundred kilobytes.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html) You would not use a plist for storing user generated data, since over time they might exceed that limit, only use it for data whose size you control.

Comment: Thanks for the source. Appreciated

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct if it helped you